# How to create an SKEmitterNode with particles already formed

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skemitternode

I am trying to create a star field with an SKEmitterNode, and I have gotten it to work.  The problem is that when it is first added to the scene, it takes a few seconds to fill the screen.  I want it to be so that as soon as the node is added to the scene, the entire star field fills the screen and then the emitter continues to emit particles.  I have attached a link to a video showing what it looks like now.
[Video on Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z1w8a2kmt54xtx4/ReflectorRecording.mov)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can advance the emitter in time manualy using [advanceSimulationTime:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKEmitterNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKEmitterNode/advanceSimulationTime%3a).

Comment: PSA: when using advanceSimulationTime, be aware that it is not a deferred action. i.e. if you call advanceSimulationTime() and then you set some properties (e.g. scale) on the emitter, then those latter changes will NOT be reflected in the scene until some time has passed. (It appears that SpriteKit either performs the simulation immediately or takes a copy of the existing properties for later execution.)Therefore, ensure you set all the properties you need on the emitter and afterwards, lastly, call advanceSimulationTime().